# Does Google Cloud translate cost multiple or once?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

Google Cloud Translate costs around $ 20 per 1 million characters. If a page is translated multiple times by different users in the same language, will the translation of the characters be billed multiple times or once?

Comment: The cost is per word translated. Google Translate does not reuse your previous translation for the purpose of reducing your bill.

Answer (score 1):

You are charged for the amount of text that Cloud Translation processes, such as the text that you include in a detect language or translate text request. Cloud Translation detects the source language for you, if you don't specify it for the translation method.

You are only charged for the text that you provided.There's no additional charge for the detection besides the translation. For example, if you submit 1,000 characters for translation without specifying the source language, you are only charged for the 1,000 characters.

Charges are scaled to the number of characters actually provided to Cloud Translation. For example, if you send 575,000 characters for processing within a month, you are charged $1.50. The first 500,000 characters are free for every month, and then you are charged for the additional 75,000 characters sent for detection, translation or both. Refer to the [link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing#translation_api_-_advanced) for pricing information per month.

As suggested by @John Hanley,Cloud translation does ignore the previous translation processes and will charge per the amount of text that is requested to translate.